# WCF DataService (OData) Timeout

Tags: wcf, odata, wcf-data-services, azure-web-roles

There is a WCF DataService(OData) developed and deployed as azure webrole accessing the SQL Azure database using Entity Framework.
It works well on tables with fewer rows.
But there are also some tables with millions of rows. When trying to access, timeout occuring.
Is there a way to avoid timeout?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase `closeTimeout`, `receiveTimeout`, `openTimeout` and `sendTimeout` for a wcf service in `web.config` like:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IManagementService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
        openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
```

For more details refer: [Configuring Timeout Values on a Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924831%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)